# unable to generate csv file from data coming from joining of two tables in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am facing the problem when generating a CSV file with data from the join of two tables. I am not facing any problems when generating CSV file with data coming from a single MySQL table. the data in both the tables is utf-8 general_ci encoded.I can see the data in the network response but not in the CSV file.

```
$subjects = $this->subject_m->get_subject_call($class);
$csv_array = array();
$csv_array_first_row = array('roll','section','exam type');
foreach ($subjects as $key => $value) {
    $csv_array_first_row[] = $value->subject;
}
$csv_array_first_row[] = "total";
$csv_array_first_row[] = "maximum marks";
$csv_array_first_row[] = "grades";
$csv_array_first_row[] = "points";
$csv_array_first_row[] = "rank";
$csv_array[] = $csv_array_first_row;
array_to_csv($csv_array,'ttt.csv');
```

the output is supposed to be the following excel row

```
roll    section name    examtype    english maths   social  science gk  total   max marks   grades  points  rank
```

But the output is

```
roll    section exam type   total   maximum marks   grades  points  rank
```

Comment: After $subjects =.... add in a new line with var_dump($subjects); to display what you are getting back from your model... and what is $class set to?

Comment: You have to print the $csv_array and see the output first

Comment: here is the $csv_array `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => roll
            [1] => section
            [2] => exam type
            [3] => English NEw
            [4] => Mathematics
            [5] => Science
            [6] => Social Studies
            [7] => Sports
            [8] => total
            [9] => maximum marks
            [10] => grades
            [11] => points
            [12] => rank
        )

)`

Comment: @harishdurga: Upload your array_to_csv function also so i can check.